# How to capture a Processes STDOUT and STDERR line by line as they occur, during process operation. (C#)

Tags: c#, process, stdout, stderr

I am going to execute a Process (lame.exe) to encode a WAV file to MP3.

I want to process the STDOUT and STDERR of the process to display progress information.

Do I need to use threading? I can't get my head around it.

Some simple example code would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I found the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that shows how to read both stdout and stderr with threads helpful. See also http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/api/csharp/html/T_CleanCode_IO_ExecProcess.htm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If running via the `Process` class, you can redirect the streams so you may process them.  You can read from stdout or stderr synchronously or asynchronously.  To enable redirecting, set the appropriate redirection properties to `true` for the streams you want to redirect (e.g., `RedirectStandardOutput`) and set `UseShellExecute` to `false`.  Then you can just start the process and read from the streams.  You can also feed input redirecting stdin.

e.g., Process and print whatever the process writes to stdout synchronously

```
var proc = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"SomeProcess.exe")
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
    }
};
if (!proc.Start())
{
    // handle error
}
var stdout = proc.StandardOutput;
string line;
while ((line = stdout.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // process and print
    Process(line);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: This does not capture STDERR.

Comment: @Albin: Well obviously, I didn't write the example to do so.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to listen to the STDOUT with the [`Process.OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event. There is an example on the MSDN page. There is also an [`Process.ErrorDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) event for STDERR.

Answer (score 6):

There is [an MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) for this... Here is a simplified version:

```
var StdOut = "";
var StdErr = "";

var stdout = new StringBuilder();
var stderr = new StringBuilder();

var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"something.exe";
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = psi;
proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { stdout.AppendLine(e.Data); };
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => { stderr.AppendLine(e.Data); };
proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit(10000); // per sachin-joseph's comment

StdOut = stdout.ToString();
StdErr = stderr.ToString();
```

Comment: Always call `waitForExit` with a timeout to prevent the chance of an infinite wait. `waitForExit(10000)` => waits for 10 seconds.