# c# CreateProcess() how to redirect the process stdout and stderr and get it in real time?

Tags: c#, redirect, stdout, stderr, createprocess

In my C# application, I need to start a child process in suspend (to register its ProcessID to some profilers) and then run it.

achieving this was possible by using the native CreateProcess() Api.
my problem is, I can't figure out how to redirect its stdout and stderr back into my C# application in real time.

before the need for the suspend option, I used System.Diagnostics.Process's "OutputDataReceived" and "ErrorDataReceived" to get the output in real time do some parsing on it.

my question is: how can I achieve the same behavior using "CreateProcess()" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112097/how-to-capture-a-processes-stdout-and-stderr-line-by-line-as-they-occur-during?rq=1

Comment: @Gabriel, that works for System.Diagnostics.Process not the native CreateProcess()