# C# how to organize error message returning between two app

Tags: c#

I have console application which is executed in another app. The problem is that the second app cannot catch the exceptions that first one throws (run with Process). So I have to write some class that contains my return code and appropriate message.So that the app which runs my executable can use it and show error message depending on return code. But I don't know how this kind of thing should be done.

Comment: Why don't you start your `Process` within a `try-catch` and catch the error there?

Comment: `process.ExitCode` contains the return of `int main()` (or `Environment.Exit(X)`)

Comment: You can catch all exception in each application.Do you want it?

Comment: ChristophKn: The first app cannot catch the exception that was thrown by second.

Comment: Alex K: I understand but I also need error message , not only code. So the runner could somehow get message regarding to error code

Comment: Use a dictionary<int, string> to map codes to strings?  You could share an assembly hosting an enum of possible values.  Or you could have the console app output the message string to stderr and read it back.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post i stumbled on but why not answer?

I think what you are looking for is the error stream.  In windows and most other systems the OS references it as `stderr`.  I'll post some links for reading, but in essence, separate execution environments or applications only return codes that tell the OS weather or not an application exited (finished) successfully (0) or encountered an error (-1).  In windows there are two separate streams `stdout` which we write execution messages to, or `stderr` which we write errors too. Those steams can then be read by your other application.  Look at these for more info:

[How to capture a Processes STDOUT and STDERR line by line as they occur, during process operation. (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112097/how-to-capture-a-processes-stdout-and-stderr-line-by-line-as-they-occur-during)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Depending on your needs there are some other more complex solutions such as the "Interoperability Library" or writing to file.

Interop info:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/