Running cordova build manually works, but through c#'s Process doesnt
Recently I've developed an app that allows users to generate APK's through a website providing the source.
Manually, the user would've ran yarn run cordova build android and it would've created the APK normally, but my app is supposed to start a new Process and run that exact same command like this:
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = $@"/c yarn run cordova build android > log2.txt 2>&1",
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        LoadUserProfile = true
    }
};

process.Start();

but the log returns this:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

I've tried checking and setting the Android\Sdk\tools and Android\Sdk\platform-tools on the system's PATH, but no succcess still.
Cordova version: 12.0.0
Gradle version: 8.1.1
Any ideas?

What user account is running the website code? How is this code hosted? Is there a reason you're executing "cmd" rather than yarn directly, other than for STDOUT/SDTERR redirection?

The user is using the Administrator account inside a server that is also hosting the code. I tried running a whoami to check if the process was running as the Administrator and it is. I'm executing cmd only for the redirections, yes. The code is being hosted on IIS

If you haven't explicitly set in the IIS app pool the Windows user that runs the pool, then it's running as the default IIS user (which depends on your version of IIS). You may want to set a specific service account to use, then ensure the tools are installed for that user.

As for stream redirection, it's easy to capture STDOUT/STDERR from C# directly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112097/how-to-capture-a-processes-stdout-and-stderr-line-by-line-as-they-occur-during This reduces the complexity of your code by allowing you to run "yarn" directly.
